rsync shell expansion, preserve wildcard directories in output
I am using a shell expansion pattern (or is it called globstar?) with rsync (it is performing much faster for me than filtering, when the input directory contains 10's of thousands of files). But I am having trouble achieving my desired output-directory structure. See the self contained example below to see what I mean:
mkdir -p targetvolume/targetdir/a/my_folder
mkdir -p targetvolume/targetdir/b/my_folder
mkdir -p targetvolume/targetdir/c/my_folder
mkdir outputdir

touch targetvolume/targetdir/a/my_folder/file1.txt
touch targetvolume/targetdir/b/my_folder/file2.txt
touch targetvolume/targetdir/c/my_folder/file3.txt

Now if I run this:
sync -ahv targetvolume/targetdir/**/my_folder/ ./outputdir
the outputdir will look like this
#ls outputdir
file1.txt       file2.txt       file3.txt

But I want it to look like this:
a/my_folder/file1.txt
b/my_folder/file2.txt
c/my_folder/file3.txt

I can't figure this out. adding the -R flag doesn't work for me because it includes the full absolute path to the files (which is very cumbersome when working with my actual data/directory, because the outputdir/directories/becomes/super/nested).

Your "shell expansion pattern" is conventionally spelled pattern or shell pattern or glob.  The last is probably clearest, but the first is the one used in the specifcations for the POSIX shell language.  "globstar" is the name of a Bash (and maybe other-shell) option that affects glob semantics.

rsync doesn't have any way of knowing which directories were written out by hand and which resulted from shell globs -- that expansion is fully complete before the shell invokes it at all.

(obviously this is different for remote paths, where the local shell sees the strings as not matching any path it knows about and passes them through unmodified; but in the examples given here it's only local paths subject to globbing)

To be clear: when you contrast with "filtering", are you talking about using rsync's built-in capabilities to apply filter rules for selecting files to sync?

@JohnBollinger, thanks for the nomenclature clarification! and RE: what I mean by "filtering": I am referring to the --filter flag and/or the  --include --exclude flags

-R does seem to be the option you need. It's just that when given the full path, the program won't know where it should be cut, which exact part you want to replicate at the destination. (Remember, it's the shell that expands the ** wildcard, while rsync just gets a list of filenames and has no idea how they came to be.) The man page gives two options:
Either, put an extra ./ in the path to mark the cut point. Indeed this seems to do what you want:
rsync -ahv -R targetvolume/targetdir/./**/my_folder/ ./outputdir

producing  outputdir/a/my_folder/file1.txt etc.
Or, cd deeper into the tree first. Though this'll require adjusting the destination too:
dest=$PWD/outputdir
cd targetvolume/targetdir/
rsync -ahv -R ./**/my_folder/ "$dest"


Thanks for all the community support! Indeed option 1 provided by @ikkachu works well for me and is succinct.

But just to be clear, this is the command that'll do it (use rsync, not sync, and for neatness just append R to the end of the flags that are already there):
rsync -ahvR targetvolume/targetdir/./**/my_folder/ ./outputdir

Use a loop so you can process each subdirectory separately.
for dir in targetvolume/targetdir/*/myfolder
do
    base=$(basename "$(dirname "$dir")")
    rsync -ahv "$dir/" "./outputdir/$base/myfolder/"
done

